# How to include SHA() in a column?

Tags: mysql

this is what i am entering. for a class i have been told to add SHA() to the pass column when creating this table, but when i do that it throws an error from googling SHA seems to need a value?

```
MariaDB \[sitename\]\> CREATE TABLE users(
\-\> user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
\-\> first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
\-\> last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
\-\> email VARCHAR(60),
\-\> pass CHAR(128) SHA() NOT NULL,
\-\> registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
\-\> PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
\-\> );
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() NOT NULL,
registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)' at line 6

I have tried googling it and i have tried including the field name in SHA() but i cant figure out how to write this correctly or if this even goes here.

Comment: seems likely to me they meant you should call SHA in your code to produce a hashed value to insert into the database.  but, even assuming that uses the SHA-2 algorithm, not the no longer secure SHA-1, that doesn't use a random salt value.  google how to do salted, hashed passwords in whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use sha-1 hashing you should use **SHA1()** in sql there is no function as **SHA()** in sql.
for passwords mysql and maria db have a specific function
**PASSWORD( string_to_encrypt )** which is most secure way.
good luck.

[this link is maria db documentation for password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/password/)